# How to write nested query in ruby on rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, where-in, subquery

i want write a query for the following using where method

```
SELECT * FROM videos 
WHERE  'privacy' = 'public' OR 
       (privacy = 'private' AND 
       id IN (SELECT vid 
              FROM vid_ads
              WHERE 'aid'=#{current_id}))
```

I tried using following query but ended with a syntax error

```
Video.where("privacy = 'public' OR 
            (privacy = 'private' AND id = ?)",
            VidAd.where(:aid => current_id).select("vid"))
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hopefully this shud work!

```
Video.where("category = #{@static_cat} AND
      privacy = 'public' OR
      (privacy = 'private' AND
      id IN (?))",
      VidAd.where(:aid => current_id).select("vid"))
```